# The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters-sql2008/2012

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the error like

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.
>          at BitSpark.Data.Databases.Database.ExecuteGetDataReader(DbCommand dbCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at BitSpark.Data.Databases.Database.ExecuteGetDataReader(DbCommand dbCommand)
>          at BitSpark.Data.DataPortal.DatabaseDataPortal.OnReadList(String metadataAssemblyName, String tableName, QueryBase q)
>          at BitSpark.Data.DataPortal.DataPortalBase.ReadList(String metadataAssemblyName, String tableName, QueryBase q)

I am doing select operation from database using bitspark Tool.

Is there any way we can increase this size limit?

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires more than 2100 parameters? The limits in SQL Server are typically pretty generous. Once you start bumping into them, questions should be asked.

Comment: let me tell a example i have splited the list to the multiple queries. 1st select statement having the list less then 2000 and bring the records let say 5000. 2nd select statement with remaining list bring 3000. In this case i should not get System Out Of Memory Exception

Comment: So you have something like a list of ids that you're trying to query on? If so, use a table-valued parameter. That is, put all 5000 in one tvp and pass that to your procedure.

Comment: can u provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to use a table-valued parameter. Here's an example in ad hoc T-SQL:

```
--Create the type only once in your database
create type myTableType as table (a int)

--This happens every time
declare @a myTableType;

insert into @a (a) values (1), (2), (3);

select * from someTable
where id in (select a from @a)
```

Once you've created a table type in your database, you can have parameters of that type (in my example `myTableType`) passed to your stored procedure. Keep in mind that they behave for all intents and purposes like a table variable.

Comment: Even in this case, sending more than 2100 parameters in the line
`insert into @a (a) values (1), (2), (3);` cause the issue

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a database limitation (SQL Server specific), not a limitation of BitSpark.

You can workaround this by querying a subset, so first a group of 2100, then the next 2100, etc.

Comment: i can split the list in chunks and execute multiple queries in parallel but is there any other way to do it. and its create the server load too.